Random debug messages appearing in terminal, vim, and zsh: "channel 0: window sent adjust [...]" on Ubuntu 22.04
When I use the terminal, vim, or zsh, a message randomly appears on a line, interrupting the text or command:
debug2: channel 0: window 999072 sent adjust 49504

Is this a bug? How to fix it?
Ubuntu 22.04.

Are you logging into this computer via screen/keyboard GUI or via ssh?  If ssh, what's the ssh command you use to connect and log in?

That's from ssh debugging. Same on SO: debug2: channel : window  sent adjust <number_2>

Those are debug messages issued by openssh's ssh client when there are adjustments to the transfer window size of a SSH channel being exchanged and the LogLevel is debug2 or higher.
They're logging events that are part of the normal operation of the SSH protocol and do not indicate any bug or error condition. You're only seeing them because you've enabled a high level of debugging (though likely not the extreme debug3 level), either because:

you've called ssh with at least two -v options,
or with -o LogLevel=debug2 or higher
or there's LogLevel debug2 or higher in /etc/ssh/ssh_config (or equivalent on your system) or ~/.ssh/config,
or you've entered ~v (possibly unknowingly) a few times to increase the log level.

That log level can also be overridden for a given function or file or  file line in the source code of ssh with the LogVerbose configuration setting; ssh -o 'LogVerbose=channels.c:*' or ssh -o 'LogVerbose=*:channel_check_window():*' for instance would also cause that particular debug message to be issued regardless of the LogLevel settings, though the format of the message then becomes:
debug2: channels.c:channel_check_window():2374 (pid=30836): channel 0: window 1900544 sent adjust 196608

So here, you'd want to check your configuration (see also the output of type ssh to see if it's aliased or wrapped in a function/script) and remove/alter those settings to disable that debugging.
Or you can enter ~V a few times (you may need to press Enter first) to decrease the log level and undo the effect of ~v.
If you still want to get debugging information but would rather not it be sent to the terminal, getting in the way of vim or zsh's line editor display, you can use the -E option of ssh to send the debug output to some file instead.
To avoid ~v increasing the log level, you can choose an alternative escape character via the -e option, or use -e none to disable those escapes altogether (see also EscapeChar in ssh_config/~/.ssh/config).
